# How to use API to bulk delete contacts quickly?

Tags: contacts, api, developer

In development I would like to use the API to delete all contacted except conctact_id  1 and 2. With Contact

This:

```
$result=civicrm_api3('Contact', 'delete', array(
      'id' => array('NOT IN' => array(1, 2)),
      'skip_undelete' => "1",
    ));
```

.. won't work even though with get it does. Would seem there is no good way to do this fast, without making a complicated MySQL query. Who knows a quick work around. Mine were extremely slow and ran into error 500 timeout errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api4 will likely to be able to do this, but it is not yet released.
It is not possible with api3. You'll need to write a custom php script to loop and call the api repeatedly, or else execute a sql query.